# Python code won't run first line prompt

Tags: python

Why won't the following python code immediately run the first line and prompt `how many years?` ?

```
years=input('how many years?')

amount=input('how much money?')

if amount < 10000:
    interest = 1.1
    total = amount * interest
    print total
else amount >= 10000:
    interest = 1.2
    total = amount * interest
    print total'
```

Comment: What does it do instead? Also, is this Python 2 or 3? You probably want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2.

Comment: Judging from the print statements, it's Python 2.

Comment: It's python 2, but he does want input() because in python 2 input is like eval(input()) in python 3. So it's a way for him to get a number, instead of a string

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error at

```
else amount >= 10000:
```

it should be

```
elif amount >= 10000:
```

And you have another syntax error on the last line, which should be

```
print total
```

(i.e. get rid of the `'`)

Comment: Thanks, the ' was made when I posted it here to get it into the gray "code" boxes on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user1198611: To get "code" boxes, indent all your code by 4 spaces. Select it in the editor and hit Ctrl+K or the `{}` toolbar button.

Answer (score 1):

In your if/else statement, the condition for amount >= 10000 is not checked for.

Change that line to

```
elif amount >= 10000:
```

and your code should compile properly.

Comment: Thanks, stupid mistake. I'm still wondering why it made it all the way down to that line rather than immediately running line 1 though?

Comment: @user1198611 From http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html : "In non-interactive mode, the entire input is parsed before it is executed." It didn't make it down to that line, the parsing failed and your program was never executed.

Comment: Always, always, always provide StackOverflow with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems.

The first is `else` should be `elif`, and there is a tick at the end of the code you posted, which I suspect might have been from posting

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running your script exactly line by line, Python actually first *compiles* your whole script into a virtual machine representation before running *any* of it. Because your script contained a syntax error (in the `else amount ...` part), Python should have indicated that to you when you tried to run it. Here's what I got when running your script:

```
$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 9
    else amount >= 10000:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You must correct this syntax error before Python will begin running your script.